# Как рассчитать точный размер полезного места в Physical Volume на LVM

Tags: linux, lvm

***Задача:*** Узнать полезный размер LVM PV до его создания.

***Контекст:***
Есть диск со свободным местом, на котором можно создать раздел и LVM PV. Известен размер свободного места. Нужно заранее, до создания раздела и создания LVM PV узнать точный объём полезного места, который будет доступен в PV после его создания.

***Приближённое решение:***
Приблизительно полезное место можно узнать как размер раздела в байтах разделить на размер экстента LVM GROUP в экспериментах все метаданные помещались внутрь округления до размера экстента.

***НО***:
В LVM Group с большим количеством разделов метаданные могут быть бОльшего размера + есть настройка хранить от 0 до 2 копий метаданных внутри LVM. Документации на точное размещение и ограничения метаданных не нашел. Всё завершилось на том что в lvm.conf есть параметр, отвечающий за размер метаданных - 255 секторов (по умолчанию). Что будет при превышении этого размера - непонятно.

Comment: остаются варианты: заглянуть в исходники, спросить у разработчиков в [списке рассылки](https://www.redhat.com/mailman/listinfo/linux-lvm) или задать вопрос на [unix.se].

Comment: В исходники пробовал заглядывать, ничего конкретного сходу там не нашел. Ну и полагаться просто на внутренности по-моему неправильно - они могут меняться без предупреждений и быть разными на разных системах (старых, новых) и т.п. поэтому особо не углублялся. Списки рассылки - да, надо попробовать. Спасибо.